# Function template specialization and the Abrahams/Dimov example

Tags: c++, template-specialization, function-templates

(I'm assuming knowledge of the [Abrahams/Dimov example](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) in this question.)

Assume there is some 3rd-party code in a header that like this, which you cannot modify:

```
template<class T> void f(T);    // (1) base template 1
template<class T> void f(T *);  // (2) base template 2
template<> void f<>(int *);     // (3) specialization of (2)
```

The question is:

If I have been given the declarations above as-is, *is it possible* for me to now specialize the base template 1 for the case where `T = int *` (for example)?

Or does the mere declaration of base template 2 imply that base template 1 can no longer be specialized (at least for pointers)?

Comment: Even if you could, would that specialization be callable? Seems like base template 2 would always "win" if f is called with a pointer.

Comment: @Mat: Not from the current translation unit, as far as I can see, but it could be callable from another translation unit, I think, right? Assuming the other translation unit has a non-overloaded declaration of #1 and of the corresponding specialization.

Comment: A TU that wouldn't have base template 2 in scope? (Not sure I understand.) Also beware of ODR violations.

Comment: @Mat: Yeah, that's what I mean. Another translation unit could declare only the first base template, along with all its specializations, but avoid defining the specialization. The specialization defined in the current TU would then be callable that way.

Comment: if the functions are not all in the same header, you could try `#include`ing them in different namespaces

Answer (score 2):

You can overload (1) by explicitly specifying the template parameter in the angle-brackets after the function name (cf. C++11-Standard 14.7.3)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T> void f(T)    // (1) base template 1
{
    cout << "template<class T> void f(T)" << endl;
}

template<class T> void f(T *)  // (2) base template 2
{
    cout << "template<class T> void f(T *)" << endl;
}
//template<> void f<>(int *);     // (3) specialization of (2)

template<> void f<int*>(int *)     // (4) specialization of (1)
{
    cout << "f<int*>(int *)" << endl;
}


int main() {
    int i;
    f(&i); // calls (2) since only base-templates take part in overload resolution
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Correct, although it's not an "overload".  It's an explicit specialization.

Comment: Could you also explicitly overload (2) by doing `template <> void f<int>(int *) { ... }`? Is that what is inferred by the commented-out (3) line?

Comment: @SamWhitlock: In the current example: Yes. In that case the specializations `template<> void f<>(int *);` and `template <> void f<int>(int *)` are the same.